# Making full hexagon a clickable link

Tags: jquery, css

I've got quite a simple problem I think for anyone more advanced in CSS then myself. Basically, I'm trying to make all the hexagons with links in them to not just have the text as a link but the full hexagon which I'm struggling to see how can be done without seriously hacking around.

Any suggestions would be fantastic!

Comment: Can you post the relevant code (and only the relevant code) directly in your question, for posterity?

Comment: Ohh sorry, you don't have to mark the question down I just forgot to link it thats all.

Comment: You may need polygon (HTML5) to realize something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use jQuery:

```
$(".about").click(function(){
 window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
 return false;
});
```

This will make your 'About Us' tab clickable .

Source:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-entire-div-clickable/

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/imemine29/6AbL9/1/
I have made it work for the 'About Us' Hex

Comment: Press update when you make changes to your fiddle that you want to share.It works for me , did you add the jQuery library in your fiddle? I have updated my post take a look.

Comment: when you hover over it only the middle bit is a link which is what it was before :S

Answer (score 1):

hi user2478101 modify your code to this

```
$('div[class^=nav-]').on('click',function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var target = $(this).find('a[href^="#"]').attr('href');
   // you code goes here
   });
});
```

E[foo^="bar"]   an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"    for more please visit http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need CSS3 or jQuery for this, just use an HTML Map tag.
This tag allows you to define multiple clickable areas which are any shape, circles or triangles etc, by defining coordinates of the points.

It's widely supported and doesn't need javascript.

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

A handy tool to help generate the coords is here: http://www.image-maps.com/